# java.lang.ClassCastException during upgrade of JSF1.2

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-1.2, tagfile

While upgrading the application from jsf 1.1 to jsf 1.2 i am getting the below error

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    Unable to convert "#{TermsOfUseBean.vin}"
to           type "javax.el.ValueExpression" for attribute "value"
at weblogic.jsp.internal.jsp.utils.JspRuntimeUtils.convertType
    (JspRuntimeUtils.java:150) at 
   jsp_servlet._termsofuse.__termsofuse._jsp__tag20(__termsofuse.java:1102)
```

Below is the tld file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
   <taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-
     jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
```

```
     <tlib-version>2.0</tlib-version>
      <jsp-version>2.1</jsp-version>
     <short-name>h</short-name>
      <uri>http://java.sun.com/jsf/html</uri>
```

Edit 2: Tld tag below that is used in jsp

```
  Tld tag used in jsp
       <tag>
        <name>inputHidden</name>
        <tag-class>com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.InputHiddenTag</tag-class>
                    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
          <attribute>
  <name>converter</name>
  <required>false</required>
  <deferred-value>
    <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </deferred-value>
   <!--<rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
  -->
   </attribute>
```

Edit 3: JSP code

```
       <h:form id="touForm">
            <h:inputHidden value="#{TermsOfUseBean.vin}"
                           id="vin">
            </h:inputHidden>
        </h:form>
```

Edit 4: Below is stack trace after changed the namespace to 2.1

```
    Static attribute must be a String literal, its illegal to specify an
     expression.
  <h:inputHidden value="#{TermsOfUseBean.vin}" id="vin">
                      ^---^
```

Comment: @BalusC do you have any idea.

Comment: As already stated, you are likely to face unusual problems regularly with those versions. Why not given them up and upgrade the application to have at least JSF 2.x? It is even quite difficult to get some help for those legacy JSF versions.

Comment: You don't even provide the JSP code where this exception appears. Seriously, it's hard to help you with the current state of your question.